# Using a mapping table to redirect unique QR encoded urls to specific wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, redirect, qr-code, url-mapping

For a local sportsclub project, i plan to generate a bunch of unique QR codes and spread them around in my local municipality. I want to keep track of which QR code is placed at which location by managing a mapping between the QR code, its location and the wordpress URL it should point to so that i can:

1. Show location specific information to the user who visits the QR encoded URL.
2. Keep track of which QR code has been scanned.
3. Be flexible with the QR codes so that i don't bind the QR code directly to the URL it should point to and use a mapping that i can configure later on.

The urls don't have to be indexed, especially because i don't want to confuse search engines, to decrease my rankings because of the redirects.

For example:
I have 50 unique QR codes that point to a url in this format:
https://site/page?1
https://site/page?2
https://site/page?3 and so on till 50

I place a QR code on a location and i register / map that code to a specific location and thus should be redirected to https://site/info-on-specific-location

Several QR codes may point to the same location, depending on the mappings.

I don't have a lot of experience with PHP or Wordpress, so my best bet would be to manually edit the .htaccess file with several mod_rewrite rules with multiple or conditions (pseudo: if id=1 or 5,15,39 redirect to location x), that i need to edit every time i assign a QR code to a location.

Can that be done without irritating search engines? Is there a way to manage this via a plugin or any other option? Or do i need to do some custom programming to achieve this?

I am just trying to think of the best way to handle this scenario.